# AS3 | Error 1009 can't fix

Tags: actionscript-3

These are the variables I'm using:

```
var isStartDrawLineTool:Boolean=false;
var myDrawingLine:MovieClip;
var temporaryDrawingLine:Shape;
```

My function (used for drawing lines):

```
drawLine();
function drawLine():void {
    if (isStartDrawLineTool == true) {
        myDrawingLine = new MovieClip();
        temporaryDrawingLine =  new Shape();
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDownLine);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUpLine);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mMoveLine);
        temporaryDrawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(brushSize, brushColor, brushAlpha);
        myDrawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(brushSize, brushColor, .5);
        desktop.addChild(myDrawingLine);
        desktop.addChild(temporaryDrawingLine);
    } else {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUpLine);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDownLine);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mMoveLine);
        temporaryDrawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x00000, 0);
        myDrawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x000000, 0);
    }
}
```

And the error I get is:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at app4_fla::MainTimeline/drawLine()
    at app4_fla::MainTimeline/frame52()
```

I couldn't find any solutions. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: desktop object where do you instantiate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stage is only available if the instance is added to stage so you need to wait for that before you try to access it.

So change

```
drawLine();
```

To

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, drawLine);
```

Also you did not state where you are defining brushSize, brushColor, brushAlpha so that may also be an issue

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving means that a variable is being referenced but has never been instantiated.

From your brief section of code, I don't see `desktop` instantiated anywhere.

I'm guessing this is a Display Object of some sort (Sprite / Movieclip) as you are trying to add a child to it. Try instantiating this variable in your `drawLine()` method too.

Answer (score 0):

It could be either your `desktop` object is null or when `drawLine()` runs it's possible your two MovieClips `temporaryDrawingLine` and `myDrawingLine` are null. This is because in `drawLine()` if `isStartDrawLineTool` is set to false (which your code doesn't show it set to true), you attempt to access both of those MovieClips which may not have been created yet.

Conversely if `isStartDrawLineTool` is true, you will instantiate the two MovieClips so they will not be null there.

You can remove the `new MovieClip()` instantiation from `drawLine()` and put it above like so:

```
myDrawingLine = new MovieClip(); //new movieclips here
temporaryDrawingLine =  new Shape();
drawLine();

function drawLine():void {
    if (isStartDrawLineTool == true) {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDownLine);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUpLine);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mMoveLine);
        .....
```